# How do you keep the order of AngularJS files when transpiling with BabelJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, babeljs

I've started to play around with using NPM Scripts and BabelJS to transpile my ES2015 AngularJS project. The problem is that the concatenated order is not correct and causes `nomod` errors.

Given this directory structure:

```
MyApp
  +- src
  |   +- dashboard
  |   |   +- search-bar
  |   |   |   +- search-bar.directive.js
  |   |   |   +- search-bar.service.js
  |   |   |   +- search-bar.spec.js
  |   |   +- dashboard.module.js
  +- dist
  |   +- js
  |   |   +- dashboard.js
```

Ideally, `dashboard.module.js` should be the first file because that is where the actual `dashboard` module is created, followed by everything in `/search-bar` which actually doesn't require any order at all. The search bar is a feature/component, not a new module and is all part of `dashboard`.

The problem seems to be that simply running BabelJS will just concatenate all the files together using the same structure as the filesystem does.

```
babel ./src/dashboard/**/*.js -o ./dist/js/dashboard.js
```

There are also weird things when messing with the wildcards to try make sure all files are captured.

How can I process `dashboard.js` first before any of the other components?

Comment: Have you considered using a module system? Babel's concatenation is really there for simple cases, concatenating JS without a bundler like Browserify is not common in modern applications.

Comment: yea, I'm starting to consider Browserify. I've been trying to simplify my toolset so it feels like I'm going backwards in that sense. It's just difficult to find solid answers to specific questions using an approach that still seems quite new. I'm totally willing to accept that the answer to _"how do you concat all these JS in the right order with babel"_ is _"you don't, you use browserify... like this..."_ but all the examples seem so simple and contrived. Not everyone is building a hobby todo app and no one seems to address the issues for enterprise applications.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can specify many globs as input files.

Try using this command:

```
babel ./src/dashboard/*.js ./src/dashboard/**/ -o ./dist/js/dashboard.js
```

This will first process any `.js` immediately inside of `/dashboard` followed by the rest of the directory.

**Gotcha:** This will only really work as long as you only have the one file inside of the `/dashboard` root. If you were to add `dashboard.config.js` or any other file, then this would process those files in that filesystem order. Unfortunately, `dashboard.config.js` comes before `dashboard.js` so your problem will continue. :(

Also, if you have other files in `/dashboard` root or you have other kinds of `.js` that you don't want to be included, you'll need to ignore them.

Try:

```
babel ./src/dashboard/**/*.js ./src/dashboard/**/ --ignore *.spec.js --ignore *.conf.js -o ./dist/js/dashboard.js
```

This will put things in the right order and also skip any `karma.config.js` or `search-bar.service.spec.js` files you may put in there. I assume that you don't want those actually being used in production.